# Why I have IndexError when program makes succesful first step?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I tried to make sorter that deletes duplicates of IP's in first list and saves it into a file, but after first succesful round it gives me IndexError: list index out of range.

I've expected normal sorting process, but it doesn't works

Code:

```
ip1 = open('hosts', 'r')
ip2 = open('rotten', 'r')
ipList1 = [line.strip().split('\n') for line in ip1]
ipList2 = [line.strip().split('\n') for line in ip2]
for i in range(len(ipList1)):
    for a in range(len(ipList2)):
        if(ipList1[i] == ipList2[a]):
            print('match')
            del(ipList1[i])
            del(ipList2[a])
            i -= 1
            a -= 1
c = open('end', 'w')
for d in range(len(ipList1)):
    c.write(str(ipList1[d]) + '\n')
c.close()
```

Comment: Your 'for' loop is not pythonic and over-complicated. In Python you just iterate over the elements and in case you really should need the index use 'for idx, element in enumerate(iterable):'

Answer (score 3):

You're deleting from the list while iterating over it, that's why you're getting an IndexError.

This could be easier done with [sets](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset):

```
with open('hosts') as ip1, open('rotten') as ip2:
    ipList1 = set(line.strip().split('\n') for line in ip1)
    ipList2 = set(line.strip().split('\n') for line in ip2)

good = ipList1 - ipList2

with open('end', 'w') as c:
    for d in good:
        c.write(d + '\n')
```

Comment: `set`s won't work here because `line.strip().split()` will return a list, which is unhashable (though that might be a mistake anyway - why is the OP reading one line at a time from the file and then splitting them on the newline character?)

Answer (score 0):

You changed lists in a fly. For expression gets a list with, as an example, of 5 elements length, after the first iteration you remove 4, so in the second iteration for tried to extract the second element but now it does not exist.
If necessary save the ordering you can use generator expression:

```
ips = [ip for ip in ipList1 if ip not in set(list2)]
```

If doesn't, just use sets expression.

Answer (score 0):

You should never modify a list that you are currently iterating over.
A fix would be just to make a third list that saves the non duplicates. Another way would be to just use sets and subtract them from each other although I do know if you like duplicates in one list itself. Also, the way you are doing it right now a duplicate is only found if its at the same index.

```
ip2 = open('rotten', 'r')
ipList1 = [line.strip().replace('\n', '') for line in ip1]
ipList2 = [line.strip().replace('\n', '') for line in ip2]
ip1.close()
ip2.close()
newlist = []
for v in ip1:
    if v not in ip2:
        newlist.append(v)

c = open('end', 'w')
c.write('\n'.join(newlist))
c.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers focus on deleting from a container while iterating over it. While that’s generally a bad idea, it’s not the crux of the problem here because you have (unpythonically) set up the `for` loops to use a sequence of indices, and so you aren’t strictly speaking iterating over the lists themselves anyway.

No, the problem here is that `i-=1` and `a-=1` have no effect: when a `for` loop begins a new iteration, it doesn’t work off of the previous value of the index. It just takes the next value that it was always destined to take, from the iterator that you established at the beginning (in your case, the output of `range()`)